# Should I use add_action('publish_post or add_filter('publish_post?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I am trying to trigger an extra function as soon as a certain custom post type is published

```
function insert_table_products($post_id, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'custom-products') {
        global $wpdb;
        $custom_meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
        //print_r($custom_meta);
        //print_r($post);
        $attachments = new Attachments('my_attachments');
        if ($attachments->exist()) :
            $my_index = 0;
            $use_image = new SplFileInfo($attachments->url($my_index));
            $use_main_image = $use_image->getFilename();
        endif;

        $wpdb->insert(
                'products', array(
            'product_code' => $custom_meta['product_code'][0],
            'product_name' => $post->post_title,
            'product_img_name' => $use_main_image,
            'price' => $custom_meta['product_price'][0], //$POST['acf-field-price_patch'],
            'product_inventory' => $custom_meta['product_stock'][0], //$POST['fields[field_54df75e760b5e]'],
                )
        );
    }
}
add_filter('publish_post', 'insert_table_products', 10, 2);
//add_action( 'publish_post', 'insert_table_products', 10, 2);
```

Neither of the hooks work. I expected the `print_r` to show some data

BTW, I have also a update function, triggered by

```
//add_filter('edit_post', 'update_table_products', 10, 2);
```

which also doesn't seem to work correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should consider using the hook mentioned by @PieterGoosen and additionally you might want to add a `if( class_exists( 'Attachments' ) )` check into your code so it won't break if the corresponding external plugin is removed.

Comment: @birgire great spot :-)

Comment: ps: [it's rather surprising at first to see](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/plugin.php#L409-431) that the `add_action` function definition is actually only a single line of code, namely a call to the `add_filter()` function ;-)

Comment: @birgire wow never looked into the add_action function, that indeed is suprising. Thanks for the class_exists suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`publish_post` doesn't work for custom post types, the correct hook (action hook) is `publish_{$custom_post_type}`. You should use `add_action()` as this is an action hook.

I also tend to make use of the `transition_post_status` hook which is a much more universal hook as it fires everytime a post's status is changed regardless. You can use `$old_status` and `$new_status` to check the previous and new status of a post then do something.

For a new post, you can something like this: (*Requires PHP 5.3+*)

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{

    if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' != $old_status && $post->post_type == 'my_post_type' ) {

        //DO SOMETHING IF NEW POST IN POST TYPE IS PUBLISHED

    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

### EDIT

For post edits/updates, using `transition_post_status`, you can do

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{

    if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' == $old_status && $post->post_type == 'my_post_type' ) {

        //DO SOMETHING IF A POST IN POST TYPE IS EDITED

    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

For further reading regarding post status transition, you can check out [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

### EDIT 2

Custom fields, built in and from the advanced custom fields plugin uses the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook, which runs after post transition, so trying to add custom fields won't work on here

For custom post types, a new hook was introduced called [`save_post_{$post_type}`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16176) to make things easier. This hook is also recommended by the ACF forum to update custom fields.

Comment: Going to try both your suggestion tx a lot

Comment: hi pieter, i am trying your first suggestion and i am getting an WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry 'xxx' for key 'product_code'] each time. So i echoed some variables and i think  $custom_meta = get_post_meta($post_id); is empty. Now i have rewritten it by get_post_meta($post->ID); but only on refresh i see data but a duplicat key.

your second suggestion is just for new posts(inserts) and doesn't apply for edit/updates, right?

Comment: The second method can be used in many ways, not just for new posts. For edits/updates you can do `if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'publish' == $old_status && $post->post_type == 'my_post_type' )`

Comment: Tx again, i see the triggers are working but $custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID); seems to be empty. How can i fix this? Are the custom fields not yet attached?? i am using advanced custom fields (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: See my update. Hope that helps

Comment: pieter, ah i think i see and i need to save_{$post_type} as i need the custom field value for further reference. Tx again.

Comment: My pleasure, hope you get this solved. :-)

Comment: hmmm, `add_action('save_my-custom-products` doesn't trigger the function but `add_action('publish_my-custom-products` does, but not getting the custom fields ofcourse

Comment: Have you tried contacting the ACF support. There is nothing more I can think about at this stage