# Add tags to a "pending" post before publishing

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I use a third-party plugin that creates custom posts (adverts) from the front-end in two steps: **1)** after the content adding the author must push a "Preview" button and **2)** only after that he/she already can save the post. After the first step the post is saved with a pending (*advert_tmp*) status, and after the second he become "*publish*"-ed.

**This is what I want:** between these two steps to convert/save a `meta_key` values as the post tags. After some research I came to the next partially working function:

```
add_action('save_post', 'set_advert_tags');
function set_advert_tags( $post_id ) {
   if ( 'advert' == get_post_type() ) {
      $tags = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'advert_tags_field', true );
      $tags = explode( ',', $tags );
      if(!empty( $tags ))
         wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $tags, 'advert_tag' );
   }
}
```

**What is wrong:** the function doesn't create tags nor after the first step, nor after the second step, but it works when I update the post from the back-end. And here I have another problem: I can't add or assign new tags to the post from the back-end because my function disturb somehow this action, only the `meta_key` values are assigned as post tags.

Answer (score 0):

The @PieterGoosen's [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178186/25187) saved my life:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
   if( 'publish' == $new_status && 'advert_tmp' == $old_status && $post->post_type == 'advert' ) {
      $tags = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'advert_tags_field', true );
      $tags = explode( ',', $tags );
      if( !empty( $tags ) ) {
         wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $tags, 'advert_tag' );
         delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'advert_tags_field' );
      }
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```